# acumular por mes usando pandas

Tags: pandas

tengo un dataset al cual realice lo siguiente:

```
# para extraer el pais se concatena <list_df_mes> con la columna de "Country/Region" de 
la dataframe original:
df_dummy_p2_a = pd.concat([origen["Country/Region"]]+ list_df_mes, axis=1)
# agrupar por pais con el criterio de suma:
df_dummy_p2_a_concatenada = df_dummy_p2_a.groupby("Country/Region").sum()
# mostrar
df_dummy_p2_a_concatenada.head()
```

[image: me arroja lo siguiente:]

Necesito agrupar por mes y sumar el total de cada uno de estos meses y así luego poder identificar los paises con mayor numero de eventos y realizar una grafica con los 3 paises con mayores cifras.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto.